# Wrong text console output when using overloaded operators

Tags: c++, output, operator-overloading, memory-corruption

I made this program with a class who has a buffer called word and saves strings passed to it using the overloaded operator '+'. It works well, but in the output there are corrputed bytes. I don't find where is the problem.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class text {
   const char *word;
   int size;
   public:
   text(int sz);
   text(const text &cpytxt);
   ~text() { delete [] word; }
   text &operator+(const char *str);
   void operator!();
   void operator--();
};

text::text(int sz = 80) {
   if(sz <= 0) {
      cout << "Error: sz <= 0" << '\n';
      exit(1);
   }

   size = sz;
   word = new char[sz];
}

text::text(const text &cpytxt) {
   if(cpytxt.size <= 0) {
      cout << "Error: cpytxt.size <= 0" << '\n';
      exit(1);
   }

   size = cpytxt.size;
   word = new char[cpytxt.size];
}

text &text::operator+(const char *str) {
   char *tmpstr = (char *) str; // Saves constant direction into non-constant direction for later usage
   char *tmpwrd = (char *) word; // Same with the object buffer
   
   int i = 0; // Creates 'i' iterator

   while(*tmpwrd) { // Sets word direction and 'i' poiting to the last empty byte
      ++tmpwrd;
      ++i;
   }

   // Assigns each char from the string to the last empty byte of word and consecutive empty bytes
   for(; i < size && *tmpstr; ++i, ++tmpwrd, ++tmpstr) { 
      if(i == size - 1) *tmpwrd = '\0';
      else *tmpwrd = *tmpstr;
   }

   return *this; // Returns invoking object
}

void text::operator!() { 
   cout << word;
}

void text::operator--() {
   char *tmpwrd = (char *) word;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++tmpwrd) {
      *tmpwrd = '\0';
   }
}

int main() {
   
   text myTxt(1000);

   myTxt + "Hello World!" + " This is an example!";
   !myTxt;
   --myTxt;
   myTxt + "GOODBYE!";
   !myTxt;
   --myTxt;

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

[Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbVzd.png)

Changing the constructor and overloaded operator function to add a '\0' at the beginning of the word buffer and at the end respectively.

Comment: [Rule of three.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: *"It works well, but in the output there are corrputed bytes...."* How does that works well?

Comment: Re: `exit(1)` -- there are three portable values for the argument to `exit()`: `EXIT_FAILURE`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `0`. [The first two are macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status) defined in `<cstdlib>`. Both the value '0' and the value `EXIT_SUCCESS` indicate successful execution. The value `EXIT_FAILURE` indicates failure.

Comment: This looks like **undefined behavior** since you have `text::text(int sz = 80)`. Clang won't even compile the program. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ceYo6Gefh) Also [default argument, gcc vs clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313509/default-argument-gcc-vs-clang)

Comment: Pro tip for C++ beginners: after encountering a confusing error message, running a Google search and copy/pasting what comes back, such as using an explicit cast, even though the search results have nothing in common with the code, and not understanding why a cast was used in the search result (and it's fairly likely that this was wrong as well), this will always end in tears.

Comment: @user12002570 I fixed the thing with the default argument in the definition instead of declaration and as Peter Becker also commented the problem with exit() was also changed to EXIT_FAILURE, although it keeps outputting corrputed bytes.

Comment: @TobíasMilano Did you try to use a debugger? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: The operator overloading is irrelevant – it would work exactly the same if you used functions with "regular" names.

Comment: In copy constructor, you allocate memory for the word ( `word = new char[cpytxt.size];` ) but don't copy the actual characters from `cpytxt`. The memory block that `word` points to contains random garbage.

Comment: `operator+` assumes that `word` points to a NUL-terminated string. But the constructor doesn't actually make `word` point to a NUL-terminated string, but to an uninitialized buffer containing random garbage. `while(*tmpwrd)` in `operator+` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized object.

Comment: I don't believe the program shown produces the output shown. The output contains `WORLD` in all caps; but the program does not. The code you are running must be different from the code you have shown.